# How could i remove items from another search?

Tags: elasticsearch

On elastic search we make two searches, one for exact items, and another for non-exact items.
On we search **input = dev**, and on the exact result we get this item:

```
    {"_id" : "users-USER#1-name",
    "_source" : {
      "pk" : "USER#1",
      "entity" : "users",
      "field" : "name",
      "input" : "dev",
    }}
```

Then we do a second search for the non-exact results we get this item:

```
        {"_id" : "users-USER#1-description",
    "_source" : {
      "pk" : "USER#1",
      "entity" : "users",
      "field" : "name",
      "input" : "Dev1",
    }}
```

We want to remove the exact results from the first search from the second non-exact search by **pk**, we want to remove the items with the **pk**'s from the first search from the second search

I'll heavenly appreciate any idea.

For example, on the fist search we got item:

```
"_id" : "users-USER#1-name"
"pk" : "USER#1"
```

Since we got this item on the first search, we want to remove all the items with the **pks** from the second search.

So the second search would be empty:

```
empty
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Pk` ? Can you give an exemple of the desired situation ?

Comment: pk it's the id of the item on another DB.
We save an ES doc for each attribute, we want to remove the results the items with the pk from the first search from the second seach.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?